# Xml String to object in c# using XDocument

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I can't seem to parse my xml string to a custom object. Here is my code:

```
    private Account parseXmlToAccount (String xml)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("a" + xml);
        List<Account> result = 
            (
                from x in doc.Root.Elements("user")
                select new Account()
                {
                    Session = (string) x.Element("session").Value,
                    User = (string) x.Element("user").Value
                }).ToList();
        Console.Out.WriteLine("b");
        return result.First();
```

And Account.cs:

```
class Account
{
    public string Session { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Session + " " + User;
    }
}
```

and my xml string:

```
<user>
  <session>7981239761293767891</session>
  <user>873948797862364</user>
</user>
```

and my error message:

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at testMonoAndroidApp.LoginManager.<parseXmlToAccount>m__4 (System.Xml.Linq.XElement) <0x00044>
at System.Linq.Enumerable/<CreateSelectIterator>c__Iterator27`2<System.Xml.Linq.XElement, testMonoAndroidApp.Account>.MoveNext () <0x0015b>
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1<testMonoAndroidApp.Account>.AddEnumerable (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<testMonoAndroidApp.Account>) <0x000ab>
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1<testMonoAndroidApp.Account>..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<testMonoAndroidApp.Account>) <0x00093>
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<testMonoAndroidApp.Account> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<testMonoAndroidApp.Account>) <0x0003b>
at testMonoAndroidApp.LoginManager.parseXmlToAccount (string) <0x0012f>
...
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in a debugger? If not then do that. If you have which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: I have stepped trough with the debugger (MonoDevelop). The exception is cast on the 5th line in my first code part (List<Account> result = )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your root is the `user` element, so change:

```
from x in doc.Root.Elements("user")
```

to

```
from x in doc.Elements("user")
```

Comment: A user has two elements: session and user.

Comment: There is only one user at the top level, so I assume it should produce a list of one user. So no null values there?

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Account> result = (from o in doc.Elements()
             select new Account{ 
               User = o.Element("user").Value, 
               Session = o.Element("session").Value 
             }).ToList();
```